# ensuring integrity of a sequence of jpeg files

Tags: integrity

How do I ensure that a sequence of files is very hard to alter, either altering the content or removing whole files?  I'm thinking some kind of rolling checksum that also relies on the sum total of checksums already calculated that day.

But that would allow a recalculation of all checksums having removed or altered a file.  So what I'm looking for is a method of making that hard to do. The problem is the code is Python so the method used will be observable.

Perhaps multiple copies of the checksum log on remote machines?

Comment: What you are describing is a hash tree, and it indeed has the issue you are describing (recalculation necessary for any changes). However, I think what you are looking for is an _integrity checker_, such as AIDE.

Comment: yes, that looks like a useful package for overall system integrity snapshots, as long as redo it after every system upgrade, had not heard of AIDE, thanks.

Comment: One method (which bitcoin uses) is include a proof of work, so that recalculating the hash tree / hash chain becomes computationally hard to do, but if you go that way, it means you have to waste a lot of machine cycles doing proof of work and you're not safe against someone who has more computing power than you.

Answer (score 2):

An answer to your question depends on the context of your problem and attack you're worried about.

What is the same for every solution is that you can use a chain of hashes to link a new jpeg file to a chain of previous files.

If you have 3 files (a, b and c) and a hash function H, basically you calculate

```
head = H(a).
```

When the next file `b` comes along, you do

```
head = H(b | head)
```

and then for `c`

```
head = H(c | head)
```

You can then verify that nobody modified the jpg files by recalculating the whole chain of hashes and comparing it to the chain you already have.

The problem with this is that an attacker can manipulate or delete files a, b or c and recalculate the chain of hashes from the point of the first manipulation onwards.

The solution to this depends on your circumstances.

#### You trust the host which builds the hash chain

If the host is secure from tampering by an attacker, you can do as schroeder suggests and use public key cryptography to sign each new hash with your private key. This doesn't become computationally more intensive the longer the chain grows. You only ever calculate a hash over one jpg file and the last hash. You'll need to include the signature in the hash calculation of the chain.

Note that an attacker who can manipulate both the jpg files and the hash chain on another machine which wants to verify the chain can still throw away the last n files and their signed hashes, so if your jpg files aren't created regularly, it will be very difficult to detect an attacker which simply removes the last n files even if you add timestamps.

#### You don't trust the host which builds the hash chain

If you don't think the host is safe from attack, you have two options:

Either use an trusted external service to create and sign the next hash given a new jpg file hash. This host will keep track of the last hash in the chain and provide it to anyone who wants to verify the chain, so that the shortening attack described in the last section can be foiled.

or

Add a proof of work so that the host needs to spend a serious amount of time computing the next valid hash. Bitcoin does this by requiring each new block's hash to start with a certain number of 0's (its a bit more complicated, but you get the picture), so in order to find a valid block, you need to play around with a few adjustable fields in the block header until you end up with a valid hash. You can adapt this to your problem, too.

The idea here is that if an attacker wanted to change the chain of hashes, he would need to duplicate the amount of work that went into creating it. This becomes harder the farther back in the chain a manipulation is attempted. Since you seem to be running on a Pi zero, duplicating the work on a much faster processor seems easy, so the proof-of-work probably won't work for you.

Even if it was feasible, it still breaks when faced with the shortening attack. You really can't get around this problem without storing the length of the chain (or the last hash, or whatever) in a trusted location the attacker can't modify.

#### Using a blockchain

You could also use a preexisting blockchain, such as the bitcoin or ethereum blockchain. You could get your file hashes into the bitcoin blockchain, for example, by creating a new transaction for each new jpg file and storing the file hash as transaction metadata.

This would solve all the problems, but depending on how fast you needed the transactions to get incorporated into the blockchain, it would cost you money.